# In Java how to assign value to System.in?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Writing data to System.in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814055/writing-data-to-system-in)

We know that `System.in` (Standard Input) is connected to console. So whenever we write in console it will flow to this stream. But is there any way to pass value to this Standard Input without entering from console, i.e. like `System.in = "ABCD"`. I just want to imitate as the value is passing from console.

Comment: what exactly you want to do with that? I sounds something ODD. Actually you read what is there in System.in and NOT assign to it.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, there is. Use [`System.setIn(InputStream in)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setIn(java.io.InputStream)).

You can supply any subtype of `InputStream` as well, so if you want to supply a specific value, you can use the [`StringBufferInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringBufferInputStream.html), like so:

```
StringBufferInputStream s = new StringBufferInputStream("ABCD");
System.setIn(s);
```

Comment: +1 though it's declared as `public final static InputStream`

Comment: But it is not working for Multiple threads. I used System.setIn(s) in one thread and in the another thread I am using Scanner.nextLine(). When I pass the value to System.SetIn from one thread it did not make any effect to the other thread in which Scanner.nextLine() is used.  Is there any way to make it work in multiple thread?

Comment: As I read it, you have already created a `Scanner` in the second thread, *before* changing `System.in` in the first thread. The scanner holds a reference to the `InputStream` supplied to it during creation. If you'd call `System.setIn(...)` from the first thread *before* creating the `Scanner` in the second thread, it should work without problems.

Comment: Yes It works. I put Thread.currentThread().sleep(10000) (i.e 10 sec delay) and after that I created the Scanner. Even though it works it doesn't meet my requirement as I dont like to put delay. I think it is better to create a new Question... :)

Comment: Currently (2018) this solution is deprecated.

Comment: whats the correct way now?

Comment: Neither Java 9 nor Java 10 mark `System.setIn` as being deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I think that instead of having your method directly access System.in:

```
public void process() {

    byte b[] = new byte[4000];
    int bytesRead = System.in.read(b);

    ...

}
```

You should factor that out so that an input stream is passed into the method:

```
public void run() {

    process(System.in);

}

public void process(InputStream is) {

    byte b[] = new byte[4000];
    int bytesRead = is.read(b);

    ...

}
```

This gives you the same behavior, but lets you invoke the business logic with input streams of your own devising for test purposes, too.