# Attempt to TDD and unit test text user input from console for Java

Tags: java, tdd

I'm writing a unit test for the following method of my tic-tac-toe program. I would like to follow a TDD approach but the method requires user input.

```
public int[] playerMove(){
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] move = new int[2];
        move[0] = reader.nextInt()-1;
        move[1] = reader.nextInt()-1;
        return move;
    }
```

My problem is that I can't input test numbers for `move[0]` and `move[1]` since it requires user input which is supplied via `System.in`. How would simulate this during my test?

Comment: Check this thread. May be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230402/testing-console-based-applications-programs-java

Comment: Or this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814055/writing-data-to-system-in

Comment: TDD requires you to write a test first.  This is so that you will find problems like this with hard-to-test code, *before* you write the code, and so you will adopt a different design that is more testable.  And experience has shown that testable designs are also more maintainable and more flexible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Testing console based applications/programs - Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230402/testing-console-based-applications-programs-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you already have the code written, and only now you're writing the test, it's not TDD.

Regarding your problem, one way to solve this is to have the `InputStream` passed as a parameter to the constructor to the class you're testing, rather than hard-coding `System.in`.

This will enable you to create an instance of the tested class with a mock `InputStream` that generates whichever input you want.